# extract field values and apply it as css color value

Tags: javascript, drupal, twig, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I'm running drupal 8 and I have a content type with the following fields

- Image
- background color scheme
- title

I have view with 4 grids

now what i want to do is get the value from the *background color scheme* field and apply it as background color...

```
<div class=grid1>    </div>
<div class=grid2>    </div>
<div class=grid3>    </div>
<div class=grid4>    </div>
```

is there a way to do this using javascript .... each div will have diff background color.

Comment: why not just preprocess the container and apply the background so you don't rely on javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider the input field for the background color scheme. You can retrieve the value of the input field using the javascript `value` method.

```
<div class="grid">    </div>
<div class="grid">    </div>
<div class="grid">    </div>
<div class="grid">    </div>

<input class="scheme" type="text" />
<input class="scheme" type="text" />
<input class="scheme" type="text" />
<input class="scheme" type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var grids = document.getElementsByClassName('grid');
  var colorinput = document.getElementsByClassName('scheme');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    grids[i].style.background = colorinput[i].value;
  }
</script>
```

Make sure to place the script after the grids, to avoid invalid reference errors.